# Declaring variables in a list, but defining them in a loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there any way to declare a bunch of variables in a list, and then define them in a for loop like so?

```
myList = [a,b,c,d]

for var in myList:
var = 1
```

So that a, b, c, and d would all end up as 1? Right now if I try and run this code I get an error telling me "a is not defined".

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be better to use a dictionary for what you want.

```
>>> my_vars = {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'd': 1}
>>> print my_var['a']
>>> 1
```

Or `my_vars = dict((x, 1) for x in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])`

Comment: Great answer, but `my_vars = {var: 1 for var in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}`, or, better yet, `my_vars = {var: 1 for var in 'abcd'}` may be even nicer.

Comment: I wrote that originally, but I figured the question asked for a list, so I stuck with that.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost always a very bad idea, but here's how you can do it if you must:

First, you need to put the *names* of the variables in the list, not the variables themselves. As the error is telling you, `a` isn't defined yet, so you can't put it into a list. And, even if it *were* defined, you'd just be putting the value of `a` into the list, which wouldn't help you. So:

```
myList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Then, you just need to add them to globals (or locals, or builtins, or the class you're currently defining, etc., depending on what namespace you're trying to define them in).

```
for var in myList:
    globals()[var] = 1
```

---

If you want to access the variables dynamically, you're going to need the same kind of tricks to *use* the variables you just defined. Why bother? Just put them in a dictionary:

```
myDict = {var: 1 for var in myVars}
```

Or maybe a custom object, or a [`namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
myNames = namedtuple('namespace', myList)(1 for _ in myList)
```

Then you can access them as:

```
myDict['a']
myNames.a
```

Compare that to what you have to do if you're trying to make them variables:

```
globals()['a']
```

---

And if you're just looking for a more concise way to declare them statically, this obviously isn't helping. Compare the three lines of complicated code with the normal version:

```
a = b = c = d = 1
```

---

Really, whenever you have to use `globals` and friends (or, similarly, `setattr` and friends), you're forced to step back a level in your head, and start mixing up variable names as strings.

There are occasionally good reasons to do this (more often for `setattr` than for `globals`), but they're not that common. Whenever you *think* you want this, the first step should be to ask yourself (or other people) if there's a better way to solve your actual problem so it isn't needed.